# ng serve with --poll option causing infinite reloads

Tags: build, angular-cli

After upgrading to Angular 12, my application is suffering from infinite reloads. This was working fine in Angular 11. I can only assume that something somewhere is putting files into the area being watched by angular. I've tried running serve in both production and development and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I can see no files being generated

The full command  I am running is

`ng serve --poll 1000`

If I remove the poll command, it works fine (and then my changes are not picked up). This issue also occurs on `ng build --poll 1000 --watch`.

[image]

What can I try to remedy this? Is there a way I can tell angular to say why it rebuilt?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread can help,

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20891

It looks like an Angular bug and there appears to be a completed PR that fixed it. You could try updating the minor or patch versions of Angular to grab that patch.

Comment: Currently running 12.1.1. Upgrading my cli to 12.1.2 has actually fixed the problem they mentioned in regards to the double build. However, the infinite build loop is still occurring with the `--poll` flag

Comment: I have the same problem, with
Angular CLI: 12.2.9
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.9

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.9
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.9
@schematics/angular             12.2.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5

Comment: Something new?? Please!